# Can you send a Start, Stop and Set Time MIDI messages to GarageBand?

Tags: midi, garage-band

While standard Start/Stop/"Set Time" MIDI messages work with Logic Pro, sending them to GarageBand doesn't do anything (I only see GarageBand getting MIDI messages, but it doesn't do anything with them).

Is it possible to have GarageBand start, stop and set the time through MIDI? What would be the codes?

I tried to find MIDI codes on the web, but playing with them didn't work (I lost the URLs, now). I also tried [GarageRemote](https://www.muratnkonar.com/otherstuff/garageremote/), which somehow converts MIDI messages to GarageBand messages, but I didn't succeed either.

PS: for reference, for Logic Pro, the following MIDI sequences do work (after "F0 7F 7F 06", and before a closing "F7"):

- Start: 02
- Stop: 01
- Set time: 44 06 01 hour minutes seconds frac_seconds 0

PPS: someone else had the [same question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipadmusic/comments/7a4rs5/does_garage_band_accept_midi_clock_or_at_least/)… and got no answer. But that was three years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but it might help you a bit further? It seems you can send start and stop midi signals from a controller to Garageband, e.g. here in the Nektar GX 61 manual p.12 (http://support.nektartech.com/Downloads/Impact_Guides/Nektar_DAW_Integration_for_Impact_GX49_and_61_English.pdf) it shows how you can use the transport buttons on the keyboard to control GB.

So, yeah, start and stop I think should be possible.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. There is hope. Now, for all practical purposes, I would need to get the MIDI sequences, but knowing that they exist helps targeting searches.

Comment: @EricOLebigot Somebody seems to have figured it out: https://www.muratnkonar.com/otherstuff/garageremote/ Maybe you can send them a mail?

Comment: Yeah, that's the app I had tried, and it didn't work. Good idea, about sending an email. Will do.